# Flash Drive/External Drive driver not recognized - Windows 8.1

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, device-manager

I can't find a solution to my problem. I'm connecting a flash drive to my laptop and Windows doesn't recognize it... 
The same drive was used to be recognized and all of a sudden it doesnt work anymore.
I've tried using different ports, different devices, uninstalling the driver and nothing helped.
When I look in Windows's device manager the flash driver appear under "Other Devices" with a yellow exclamation mark near it, giving the error code of 28 - Driver not installed.
When looking in Disk Management the drive doesn't show.

I've tried removing all of the usb drivers, updating my Intel driver set, and still no response...

Im clueless....  Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually i used Windows Repair/Refresh I don't remember whats it called.
It restored my Windows entirely while keeping my files.. 
Now I have to re install every software, but it solved the problem..thank god